# Problema al contar palabras de cadenas usando diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

Hola estoy trabajando en un programa donde un usuario puede poner cualquier tipo de palabras y mi programa saca las diferentes tipos de palabras y el top 5 de palabras mas usadas este es mi codigo:

```
contador = {} 
grupo = {} 
while True :
        palabras=input("ponga palabras aqui ")
        if palabras.lower() == "x":
                break
        for linea in palabras:
          palabras = linea.split() 
        for palabra in palabras:
            palabra = palabra.lower().strip(".,") 
            if palabra not in contador:
                contador[palabra] = 1
            else:
                contador[palabra] += 1

            longitud = len(palabra)
            if longitud not in grupo:
                grupo[longitud] = { palabra } 
            else:
                grupo[longitud].add( palabra )
print("total de palabras distintat" , len(contador))

print('Las diez palabras más comunes son:')
for palabra in sorted( contador, key = contador.get, reverse=True )[:5]:
    print('\t',palabra,':',contador[palabra],'ocurrencias')
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que toma solo una letra: si pongo una palabra solo toma la última letra de la palabra. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que tome toda la palabra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sobra un `for`:

```
for linea in palabras:
```

De `input` recibes una cadena, no líneas. En el primer `for` iteras sobre los caracteres de la cadena. `split` se aplica por tanto sobre este carácter, no sobre una cadena. Tu código es correcto si iteraras sobre un fichero o sobre una lista de cadenas.  En tu caso  debe ser algo así:

```
contador = {} 
grupo = {} 
while True :
        palabras=input("ponga palabras aqui ")
        if palabras.lower() == "x":
            break
        for palabra in palabras.split():
            palabra = palabra.strip(".,") 
            if palabra not in contador:
                contador[palabra] = 1
            else:
                contador[palabra] += 1

            longitud = len(palabra)
            if longitud not in grupo:
                grupo[longitud] = { palabra } 
            else:
                grupo[longitud].add( palabra )
print("Total de palabras distintas" , len(contador))

print('Las diez palabras más comunes son:')
for palabra in sorted( contador, key = contador.get, reverse=True )[:5]:
    print('\t',palabra,':',contador[palabra],'ocurrencias')
```

si no tienes limitaciones en cuanto a que recursos de la biblioteca estándar usar, te recomiendo que te mires [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) y el método `most_common()`, en Python 3 puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
from collections import Counter


contador = Counter()
while True :
    palabras = input("Ponga palabras aqui: ")
    if palabras.lower() == "x":
            break
    contador.update(palabra.strip(",.").lower() for palabra in palabras.split())

print("Total de palabras distintas:",  len(contador))
print('Las diez palabras más comunes son:')
print(*('\t{}: {} ocurrencias.'.format(pal, n) for pal, n in contador.most_common(10)), sep = "\n")
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho no podia encontrar el error

Comment: @Microplo de nada, cuando te bloquees y no seas capaz de hacerte el mapa mental del algoritmo para ver donde falla te recomiendo usar  `print` con fines de depuración exclusivamente en cada paso del algoritmo, `print(linea)` en el primer `for`, `print(palabra)` en el segundo, etc. Por si te interesa he creado un ejemplo con `collection.Counter` que es mucho más eficiente a la hora de contar apariciones en iterables por si te interesa. Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias,agradesco tu ayuda pero creo que estoy bien pero muchas gracias de todos modos, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

creo que ayduaria mas un ejemplo como este en el cual puedes realizar el conteo de palabras con funcione ya regitradas en el sistema como len(variable)que te permite contar todos los caracteres de una variable o bien lo que le indiques que cuente (.split(' ')) te permite contar los es pacios y sabemos que cada palabra estaria dividida con un espacio todo se hace mas directo ejemplo:
hariamos un contedo de los splits para que contara cuantas palabras

```
palabra= input("ingrese texto") #estaria guardando el texto

print("el total de palabras es") #solo indicacion para mencionar el conteo


print(len(palabra.split(' ')))   # aqui estaria contando el total de espacios en las palabras 
dicienco que cada palabra se separa con un espacio te daria el total de palabras.
```